# How to say 'Is this you in this photo'?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean, korean-to-english

Is it '이 사진을 너는 예요?'or '이 너의 사진 예요'? I also read somewhere that's it's '사진에 넌 예요?' If yes why 에?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'이 사진을 너는 예요?'or '이 너의 사진 예요'
both doesn't make sense.

이 사진이 당신이에요? are closest.

이 사진이 너에요? sounds a bit not natural.

It's depending on who you talking to...

Because the Korean language varies a lot.

- Very informal way. (to your buddy)

사진, 이거 너 야? (This picture, is this you? )

- Moderate. (to someone, who you just start to talk)

사진에 있는 사람, 이거 본인이세요? (The person in the picture, is this you?)

Comment: Sorry but I have to disagree with the last sentence.  Contrary to some textbooks, 당신 is almost never a correct word for _you_, unless you want to start a fight.

Comment: I agree with @jick here. 당신 is almost never used colloquially, except to provoke someone. Koreans usually use "그쪽" or "선생님" for that kind of sense, so it would be natural to say "사진에 있는 이분이 선생님이세요?".

Comment: Yes, you are right. you would better say, '본인' instead. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!